# Best factor for Partial Profiting

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Regarding the market and stocks.

Everytime I enter a position (buying a stock let's say) I have a starting point and a desired one where I'll take the profit (selling it).

Since it happens so little times that I get to that profit I've decided to split the profits in parts, Partial Profits.

Let's imagine that I buy 1000 stocks at a certain price. At that moment we are, in terms of distance between the starting point and the maximun profit, at 0. If the movement goes against me I'll lose but that's OK. So, 0 is where everything starts and 10 is where maximun gains happen. In between I have the partial profits (1, 2, 3 all equally distant between each other) so my question is, which % of my 1000 stocks should I extract/sell at each point? For that I have a set batch of data out of a backtesting enviroment.

According to my numbers, I simulated 434 tries, these are the numbers I reached to each partial profit. (I left aside the times that the transaction goes wrong).

[image]

As expected, numbers keep decreasing as we approach the final one. At first I assigned 10% of the entire position for every partial profit. That would mean when Partial Profit #1 happens, I sell 10% of my 1000 stocks and keep the other 90% waiting for other Profits. When Partial Profit #2 happens, I sell another 10% leaving me with 80% and so on.
After looking at these numbers I realize there should be a different set of percentages for each profit number that would maximize the gains.

Is there a way or mathematical equation to get the best factor? Just for the purpose of confirming it I did a quick run of this set and yes, ending number was way better,  but is there a way to knowing the best approach? And maybe it can be applied to other backtesting results since what I'm showing here is just one example.

Thanks in advance

[image]

PS. In case you can make use of the information: Let's say I reach Profit #5 and then the stock goes down, I'd sell the remaining % at Profit #4.

Comment: Based on your description, I would try to maximize partial profit $\times$ number of times.  Based on this approach it seems like the best that you can do is always wait until it looks like the stock is a loser, and then completely liquidate it, or the stock simply isn't going to move, and completely liquidate it (thus breaking even, except for the commisions), or until the stock goes up two points, and then completely liquidate it, settling for the two points of profit.  Based on your data, trying to keep some of your % investment hoping for a bigger payoff is too *pie* *in* *the* *sky*.

Comment: An exception here, is if the stock has only lost one point, or has not moved, you might consider hoping to get lucky, and giving the stock 6 months, to see which way it moves.  This approach is geared towards consideration of the commissions, which you want to minimize.  Then, you have the vast complications of *timing* capital gains, re taxes and re offsetting capital losses (if any), short term versus long term capital gains, stock dividends, changing market conditions, and so forth.

Comment: The bottom line is that you are up against professional *sharks*.  Investing is a profession, just like open heart surgery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I appreciate it. My question aims to a mathematical equation to get to the right approach to set the percentages for every profit in a set of 10 of them. Other implications like the ones you mentioned are already being considered. So when that's on the side and I'm left with a case of this (the example on my question), what's the best approach? That's where I'm trying to get. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your data, any time that the stock rose $2$ points, I would always immediately liquidate all of it.  So, the the % that remains invested after the stock hits $+2$ is $0$%.  This is my immediate reaction to your first chart.  As I said, looking at that chart, for each value of $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, 10\}$, multiply [Partial profit $= k$] $\times$ corresponding number of times, and the *mathematical* conclusion will be immediate.

Comment: There is something else: the whole idea of trying to use math, as you are, to drive decisions, already suggests that you have gone off the rails.  While the math, re commissions, dividends, taxes, interest rates, apparent current market volatility, risk aversion versus risk seeking, and diversification are  relevant, these factors should *become* secondary to some sort of analytical or informational edge.  In investing, either you are a shark, or a flounder, and flounders get eaten.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. And it makes sense. My aims was for a general equation so I could apply to other set of backtesting data. Because in this example it totally makes sense to close the full position after Profit #2. But there are others where the distribution is a bit different. But I can clearly see your point. It's much appreciated and rings a few bells.